# Fragment Hide do not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created just sample application for fragment hiding and showing.At the first fragment is added into the view properly.But on menu press to hide fragment it don't get hide.I posted my code as follows..

```
public class SwapfragActivity extends Activity
{

FrameLayout fr;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    fr = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fm1);

    frag f = new frag();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    menu.add("SHOW");
    menu.add("HIDE");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    frag f = new frag();
    if (item.getTitle() == "SHOW")
    {
        if (!f.isAdded()) 
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fm1, f);
            ft.commit();
        }
        else if (f.isHidden())
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.show(f);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (f.isAdded()) 
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(f);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}

class frag extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.a, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably because of the string comparison: `item.getTitle() == "SHOW"`. In Java, you *can't* use the `==` operator to compare strings; in stead write: `item.getTitle().equals("SHOW")`.

Comment: Was that the issue? I'm doing fragTransaction.hideA(frag) but the fragment still shows up although the test for frag.isHidden shows up correctly.